# Update state with Nested object in Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am having some troubles trying to update nested object using useState. I have a form where users can add/edit Car information. So basically i am handling the car in a local state to display the data in a form.

```
 //Local state to handle a Car
const [car, setCar] = useState({
    brand: "Mazda",
    vin: "JMB838783S",
    location: {
      address: "9098 West Alabama Street",
      lat: "-22.73984",
      long: "8.44538",
    },
    contact: {
      phone: "+16758907676",
      email: "car@provider.com",
    }
  });
```

However when I tried to edit the information of address or phone, I cannot get it work using function in **onChange**

```
const handleInputChanges = e => {

    setCar({
      ...car,
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
};
```

**Form**

```
<FormContainer onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <DropPictureZone onImageDropped={setThumbnailDropped} />

            <InputText
              type="text"
              name="brand"
              placeholder="Brand"
              value={name}
              onChange={handleInputChanges}
            />

            <InputText
              type="text"
              name="address"
              placeholder="Address"
              value={location.address}
              onChange={handleInputChanges}
            />

            <div className="p-grid">
              <div className="p-col">
                <InputText
                  type="text"
                  name="lat"
                  placeholder="Latitude"
                  value={location.lat}
                  onChange={handleInputChanges}
                />
              </div>

            <div className="p-grid">
              <div className="p-col-4">
                <InputMask
                  mask="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx"
                  name="phone"
                  placeholder="Phone Number"
                  value={contact.phone}
                  onChange={handleInputChanges}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="p-col">
                <InputText
                  type="text"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  value={contact.email}
                  onChange={handleInputChanges}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <Button label="Save" />
          </FormContainer>
```

What is the right way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show your form code?

Comment: Your `car` state object has nested values. Your `handleInputChanges` does not account for this. You'll either need to add some awareness to the change handler, or put all your state values on the same level.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer Form code added!

Comment: @BrianThompson That is the way API returns data

Comment: So as Brian Thompson mentioned, `.name` is not the correct path to the property in the object, as the object is nested and you are assigning it directly to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of correct answers to this problem. Here is one:

Modify your change handler to accept a curried parameter informing it which nested object to update.

The new handler would looks something like this:

```js
const handleInputChanges = level => e => {
  if (!level) {
    // Assume root level
    setCar({
      ...car,
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
  } else {
    setCar({
      ...car,
      [level]: {
        ...car[level],
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
      }
    })
  }
};
```

Then modify your form like this:

```js
<InputText
  type="text"
  name="brand"
  placeholder="Brand"
  value={name}
  onChange={handleInputChanges()} // Root level
/>

<InputText
  type="text"
  name="address"
  placeholder="Address"
  value={location.address}
  onChange={handleInputChanges('location')} // location object
/>

<InputMask
  mask="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx"
  name="phone"
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  value={contact.phone}
  onChange={handleInputChanges('contact')} // contact object
/>
```

This is just an example of each type, you'll need to modify each field.

Comment: What about if has 20+ fields with nested values?

Comment: Well first, I just updated with a much more flexible handler. But really, if your data is that complex you are going to have to expect a slightly more complex form. Its just natural. This is a pretty flexible solution though.

Comment: Good solution by Brian, also you can read this post: https://medium.com/@katestamas/dynamically-update-states-in-react-7558287e5fb9

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try @BrianThompson answer. I will let them know

Comment: @BrianThompson I love you.